# How to express the argument through the function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I would like to express argument $d$ through $f$ and $B$ and to get $d(f,B)$
$$f(d,B)=B\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{d}{B}\right)\left( 1-\left(1- e^{-30d/B} \right)^8\right)+\frac{2/B}{3+1/B^2}\left(1- e^{-30d/B} \right)^8\right)$$

How to do it in Mathematica (analytically or numerically)?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[d_, B_] := B*((1/4 - d/B)*(1 - (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8)+
(2/B)/(3 + 1/B^2) (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8);
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is `d` a function or a variable? Do you want to solve for d and then substitute that result? Did you instead mean `f(f(d,B),B)`?

Comment: @alex, yes d is a variable, I would like to express d through f and B

Comment: Hi @Mam Mam, I'm terribly sorry, but I feel that I do not fully understand your question. I don't think you have added any further addition to what was on your post.

Comment: apologies, I just saw that you edited your post since my last comment. Give me a second.

Comment: Do you need this for plotting?

Comment: @yarchik, no, I would like to repeat results from this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05553.pdf .The authors do the same operation in the formulas (14) and (10), namely they to express $\beta_j$ through $\Delta_j$ and $B$.

Comment: If `d` is a variable, then what does `d(f, B)` mean?

Comment: But the authors of that paper did not claim they can do the inversion analytically. Most probably they did it numerically.

Comment: @yarchik, numerically mean that they did it for certain value of $B$?

Comment: Plot your function. Then you will see that there are multiple tuples {d,B} that result in the same f value. That means the inverse function will be multivalued. Can you restrict the domain, so that a single valued function results?

Answer (score 3):

No chance for mix of exponentials and powers:

```
Solve[a==f[d,B],d]
```

This one  is working at least with implicit roots

```
f[d_, B_] := 
 BB* (1 - (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8) +  (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8

{{d -> ConditionalExpression[
    1/30 b (2 I \[Pi] ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] + 
       Log[Root[-1 + 
           BB + (8 - 8 BB) #1 + (-28 + 28 BB) #1^2 + (56 - 
              56 BB) #1^3 + (-70 + 70 BB) #1^4 + (56 - 
              56 BB) #1^5 + (-28 + 28 BB) #1^6 + (8 - 
              8 BB) #1^7 + (-1 + a) #1^8 &, 1]]), 
    ConditionalExpression[1, \[Placeholder]] \[Element] Integers]
```

But it is possible to work numerically always with InverseFunction

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[d_, B_, BB_] := 
 BB* (1 - (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8) +  (1 - Exp[(-30*d)/B])^8

Plot[Re@InverseFunction[f , 1 , 3][x, 3, 4], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]